# Adding Bootstrap 4 to Slate V1 - Getting two Index in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, shopify, slate

I'm a newby when it comes to web development.  I have done some development before but not with regards to Web.

I understand the basics of what CSS is, what Javascript does and the basic HTML.

I've installed Slate, and I've downloaded the Bootstrap 4 files and added these into the new slate theme I generated under the theme.scss.liquid file.  I have added each _.scss individually as stated to do so in another thread on here.

When I do this however, some styling stops working and I noticed there is two 'index' when (on chrome) i go to View->Developer->Developer tools.

2 questions

1) I assume there is a second 'index' being loaded which is why my styling is being ignored.  How or where would this second index be loaded from?

2) I assume slate V1 ships with some styling of it's own.  Will adding the bootstrap 4 scss clash with this, and therefore do I need to remove some slate v1 styling or config?

Thanks, I realise this may be a loose question and require some further understanding on my part.

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score -1):

[Slate](https://github.com/Shopify/slate) ships with a skeleton of scss files and a (very) sparse stylesheet to show you how a folder structure might look. If you're new and just looking to use bootnap, try adding the cdn version into `theme.liquid` and start adding markup to your `html` per https://getbootstrap.com/

---

#### Just CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

---

#### JS, Popper.js, and jQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```